# Verilog did not give the expected result

Tags: verilog, display, mux

I wrote this Verilog code.  The inner module is an 8-bit mux, and the top module is used to test the mux.  It should display `11110000`, but it displayed `xxxxxxxx` every time.  How do I fix this?

```
module testbench;

reg CLK;
test mytest(CLK);
initial begin
CLK = 1'b0;
#10
CLK = 1'b1;
end
endmodule

module test(CLK);
input CLK;
reg [7:0] in0,in1;
reg sel;
wire [7:0] out;

mux myux(in0,in1,sel,out);

always @(posedge CLK) begin
    sel = 1'b0;
    in0 = 8'b11110000;
    $display("%b",out);
    end
endmodule
```

This is the `mux` module:

```
module mux(in0,in1,sel,out);
    input sel;
    input [7:0] in1,in0;
    output [7:0] out;
    reg out;

    always @(in0,in1,sel) begin

    if(sel == 1'b0) begin

        out = in0;

    end
    else begin

        out = in1;

    end
    end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you did not run your simulation long enough.  You only ran it for one clock cycle.  Here is one way to change your `testbench` module to run many clock cycles:

```
module testbench;

reg CLK;
test mytest(CLK);

initial begin
    CLK = 1'b0;
    forever #10 CLK =~CLK;
end

initial #1000 $finish;

endmodule
```

I now see output like this:

```
xxxxxxxx
11110000
11110000
11110000
11110000
```

Also, I got a compile error with your code.  In your `mux` module, you should change:

```
reg out;
```

to:

```
reg [7:0] out;
```